# Outputting or reading columns in a different order using pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Python script that reads a CSV file and outputs it to HTML.

I would like to change the order of the columns once written to the HTML file, but I don't know if I should do this on read or write or what function to use, here is my code so far.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import shutil
import glob

#paths
HTMLPATH="C:/NMS4/QUE/HTML/"
QUEPATH="C:/NMS4/QUE/"

#create the directory for holding the HTML files if it doesn't exist

isExist = os.path.exists(HTMLPATH)
if not isExist:
  os.mkdir(HTMLPATH, 0o777)

#convert .txt file to a html file in the HTML folder
#can't convert an empty file so only convert if file size in not 0
for quefile in glob.iglob('C:/NMS4/QUE/*.txt'):
  if os.path.getsize(quefile) != 0:
    csv = pd.read_csv(quefile, header=None, usecols=[0,3,4,15,34,43,44,129], names=['OrderNo','Req Qty','Planned Start','Resource','Op','Part','Desc','Qty Recd'])
    html_table = csv.to_html()
    f = open(quefile + '.html', 'w')
    f.write(html_table)
    f.close()
    shutil.move(quefile + ".HTML", HTMLPATH)
```

Any help, greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

I've been looking at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html, but can't quite find out how to re-order the columns.

Edit,
Changes to get the solution are,

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import shutil
import glob

#paths
HTMLPATH="C:/NMS4/QUE/HTML/"
QUEPATH="C:/NMS4/QUE/"

#create the directory for holding the HTML files if it doesn't exist

isExist = os.path.exists(HTMLPATH)
if not isExist:
  os.mkdir(HTMLPATH, 0o777)

#convert .txt file to a html file in the HTML folder
#python can't convert an empty file so only convert if file size in not 0
for quefile in glob.iglob('C:/NMS4/QUE/*.txt'):
  if os.path.getsize(quefile) != 0:
    csv = pd.read_csv(quefile, header=None, usecols=[0,3,4,15,34,43,44,129], names=['Order No','Req Qty','Planned Start','Resource','Op','Part','Desc','Qty Recd'])
    cols = list(csv.columns)
    a, b, c, d, e, f, g = cols.index('Order No'), cols.index('Req Qty'), cols.index('Planned Start'), cols.index('Resource'), cols.index('Op'), cols.index('Part'), cols.index('Desc')
    cols[a], cols[b], cols[c], cols[d], cols[e], cols[f], cols[g] = cols[a], cols[e], cols[f], cols[g], cols[c], cols[b], cols[d]
    df = csv[cols]   
    html_table = df.to_html()
    f = open(quefile + '.html', 'w')
    f.write(html_table)
    f.close()
    shutil.move(quefile + ".HTML", HTMLPATH)
```

Comment: You can reorder the columns not during the reading or writing stage, but just as separate step in between. How? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53141240/pandas-how-to-swap-or-reorder-columns

Comment: Used, csv = pd.read_csv(quefile, header=None, usecols=[0,3,4,15,34,43,44,129], names=['Order No','Req Qty','Planned Start','Resource','Op','Part','Desc','Qty Recd'])
    cols = list(csv.columns)
    a, b, c, d, e, f, g = cols.index('Order No'), cols.index('Req Qty'), cols.index('Planned Start'), cols.index('Resource'), cols.index('Op'), cols.index('Part'), cols.index('Desc')
    cols[a], cols[b], cols[c], cols[d], cols[e], cols[f], cols[g] = cols[a], cols[e], cols[f], cols[g], cols[c], cols[b], cols[d]
    df = csv[cols]   
    html_table = df.to_html()