Gdal tiff to csv with Lon and Lat
I want to get a normal CSV file from GeoTIFF.
I have the code:
inputfile = '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/tiff to nc/of_LC08_L2SP_169027_20130428_20200913_02_T1_SR_B5.TIF.tif'
outputfile = '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/tiff to nc/output.xyz'
from osgeo import gdal
import pandas as pd
dataset = gdal.Open(inputfile)
gdal.Translate(outputfile, dataset, format='XYZ')
df = pd.read_csv(outputfile, sep=' ', header=None, names=['x', 'y', 'value'])

As a result I get:
enter image description here
And I want to receive:
enter image description here
What should be done to get lon and lat instead of x and y?

Please don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53141240/pandas-how-to-swap-or-reorder-columns

I may be wrong about this, but at least when running gdal_translate as a stand-alone program, it cannot re-project the data, so I think you need to do the xy-to-latlon conversion as a separate step. (In the case of CSV output, re-projecting would obviously be easy, but translate is typically used to convert between image formats, where some hairy resampling would be required, which is a job for gdalwarp.)

Thanks for the reply. I do not know how to get Lat from X. I'll try to work with gdalwarp, maybe this will solve the problem.
